# HDP Ambari installation fails

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

[HDP Repo Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSXw6.jpg)

I am trying to install HDP Ambari on a 4 node cluster. Followed Hortonworks Data Platform - Automated Install with Ambari - PDF version:

Here is what I have so far:

- 4 VMs - CentOS 6
- Downloaded Amabri Repo on each server
- Downloaded HDP stack repo
- Did yum install ambari-server (on one machine)
- Did yum install ambari-agents (on all machines)
- Started Ambari Server and the Agents.
- Logged in to Ambari web console Followed the cluster creation steps and confirmed the host (No ssh keys were used. Did manual install of Ambari-agent on all machines.)
- Arranged the Services for NN, SNN, DN and so on.. (Configured services for: Hadoop, YARN, Hive and HBase)
- Verified configuration

While completing the process receive the following error:

stderr: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/before-INSTALL/scripts/hook.py", line 37, in 
    BeforeInstallHook().execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 219, in execute
    method(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/before-INSTALL/scripts/hook.py", line 34, in hook
    install_packages()
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/before-INSTALL/scripts/shared_initialization.py", line 32, in install_packages
    Package(packages)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/base.py", line 154, in **init**
    self.env.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 158, in run
    self.run_action(resource, action)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 121, in run_action
    provider_action()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/package/**init**.py", line 49, in action_install
    self.install_package(package_name, self.resource.use_repos, self.resource.skip_repos)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/package/yumrpm.py", line 49, in install_package
    shell.checked_call(cmd, sudo=True, logoutput=self.get_logoutput())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 70, in inner
    result = function(command, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 92, in checked_call
    tries=tries, try_sleep=try_sleep)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 140, in _call_wrapper
    result = _call(command, **kwargs_copy)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 291, in _call
    raise Fail(err_msg)
resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install hdp-select' returned 1. Error Downloading Packages:
  hdp-select-2.2.6.0-2800.el6.noarch: failure: hdp-select/hdp-select-2.2.6.0-2800.el6.noarch.rpm from HDP-2.2: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

============================================================================

The error is failure to download a package called hdp-select. Tried to search but didn't find any resolution to this issue. I restarted the ambari-server and ambari agents on all machines. That didn't help either. The post below does mention something similar but has no resolution.

[Link to somewhat similar issue but no resolution](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ambari-user/201502.mbox/%3C8c0ece9566e94990b1c9635e057e5e48@SESOEX0019.global.scd.scania.com%3E)

HDP and Ambari repos look fine.

What's causing the error and how to fix this?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: What is the content of your /etc/yum.repos.d/HDP.repo file?

Comment: Please see attached snapshot for HDP content.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to your internet connection issue.
Please press on 'restart' button available on the Ambari-web after encounter download failure. 
if that doesn't help, try making a local repository by copying the packages onto your local machine.

> http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.1.0.0/bk_Installing_HDP_AMB/content/_using_a_local_repository.html